# selecting with where clause with CQL

Tags: select, cql, elassandra

trying to do a select from CQL  and getting an error

SELECT uid, login, username FROM test.docs WHERE es_query='{ "query":{"nested":{"path":"username","query":{"term":{"username.first":"barthelemy"}}}}}' AND es_options='indices=test' ALLOW FILTERING;

Data is added
I am able to see the data from Elastic API.
the DESCRIBE on table is correct.

Query 1 ERROR: Operation failed - received 0 responses and 1 failures